# Convert incoming JSON string to Javascript array with ability to GroupBy

Tags: javascript, json, office-js, dynamic-arrays

I have an API which returns a JSON, like:

```
{
"CaseAssgnedDt": "2011-07-22T17:12:19",
"InquiryId": "08-CA-036441",
"DisputeUnitCity": "Cleveland",
"CaseClasification": "Unclassified",
"CaseClosedDt": null,
"Created": "2010-10-07T15:32:29",
"CaseDescription": null,
"LastUpd": "2019-10-20T17:17:14",
"LastUpdBy": "1-CGA",
"CaseName": "Sample test case name",
"CaseNumber": "08-CA-036441",
"CaseSource": "Visit",
"DisputeUnitState": "OH",
"CaseStatus": "Open",
"CaseSubType": "CA",
"CaseSubTypeCd": null,
"CaseType": "C",
"CaseLongName": "Long sample test case name",
"Num8a3Discriminatees": null,
"Num8b2Discriminatees": null,
"NumOfEmployees": 146,
"PostElectionSelfCertification": null,
"Potential10j": "N",
"RegionRecommendsPursuing10j": "N",
}
```

I am retrieving that from the API in Javascript using the Fetch API.

Once I retrieve it, I wish to convert it into a Javascript array of Name/Value pairs, matching the specific format as follows:

```
[
{fieldName:"CaseAssgnedDt", fieldValue: "2011-07-22T17:12:19"},
{fieldName: "InquiryId", fieldValue: "08-CA-036441"},
{fieldName: "DisputeUnitCity", fieldValue: "Cleveland"},
{fieldName: "CaseClasification", fieldValue: "Unclassified"},
{fieldName: "CaseClosedDt", fieldValue: null},
{fieldName: "Created", fieldValue: "2010-10-07T15:32:29"},
{fieldName: "CaseDescription", fieldValue: null},
{fieldName: "LastUpd", fieldValue: "2019-10-20T17:17:14"},
{fieldName: "LastUpdBy", fieldValue: "1-CGA"},
{fieldName: "CaseName", fieldValue: "Sample test case name"},
{fieldName: "CaseNumber", fieldValue: "08-CA-036441"},
{fieldName: "CaseSource", fieldValue: "Visit"},
{fieldName: "DisputeUnitState", fieldValue: "OH"},
{fieldName: "CaseStatus", fieldValue: "Open"},
{fieldName: "CaseSubType", fieldValue: "CA"},
{fieldName: "CaseSubTypeCd", fieldValue: null},
{fieldName: "CaseType", fieldValue: "C"},
{fieldName: "CaseLongName", fieldValue: "Long sample test case name"},
{fieldName: "Num8a3Discriminatees", fieldValue: null},
{fieldName: "Num8b2Discriminatees", fieldValue: null},
{fieldName: "NumOfEmployees", fieldValue: 146},
{fieldName: "PostElectionSelfCertification", fieldValue: null},
{fieldName: "Potential10j", fieldValue: "N"},
{fieldName: "RegionRecommendsPursuing10j", fieldValue: "N"}
]
```

So essentially, I want the equivalent of:

```
const caseData = [
{fieldName:"CaseAssgnedDt", fieldValue: "2011-07-22T17:12:19"},
{fieldName: "InquiryId", fieldValue: "08-CA-036441"},
{fieldName: "DisputeUnitCity", fieldValue: "Cleveland"},
{fieldName: "CaseClasification", fieldValue: "Unclassified"},
{fieldName: "CaseClosedDt", fieldValue: null},
{fieldName: "Created", fieldValue: "2010-10-07T15:32:29"},
{fieldName: "CaseDescription", fieldValue: null},
{fieldName: "LastUpd", fieldValue: "2019-10-20T17:17:14"},
{fieldName: "LastUpdBy", fieldValue: "1-CGA"},
{fieldName: "CaseName", fieldValue: "Sample test case name"},
{fieldName: "CaseNumber", fieldValue: "08-CA-036441"},
{fieldName: "CaseSource", fieldValue: "Visit"},
{fieldName: "DisputeUnitState", fieldValue: "OH"},
{fieldName: "CaseStatus", fieldValue: "Open"},
{fieldName: "CaseSubType", fieldValue: "CA"},
{fieldName: "CaseSubTypeCd", fieldValue: null},
{fieldName: "CaseType", fieldValue: "C"},
{fieldName: "CaseLongName", fieldValue: "Long sample test case name"},
{fieldName: "Num8a3Discriminatees", fieldValue: null},
{fieldName: "Num8b2Discriminatees", fieldValue: null},
{fieldName: "NumOfEmployees", fieldValue: 146},
{fieldName: "PostElectionSelfCertification", fieldValue: null},
{fieldName: "Potential10j", fieldValue: "N"},
{fieldName: "RegionRecommendsPursuing10j", fieldValue: "N"}
]
```

Except instead of coding that array, I want to dynamically build it from the JSON retrieved.

This is all, ultimately, to get my data in a format so that I can implement code similar to that referenced in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/correlated-objects-pattern, under the "Process objects in the document with the correlated objects pattern" section.

Please provide code to illustrate or demonstrate your solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `map` on the `Object.entries`

```js
let x = {
"CaseAssgnedDt": "2011-07-22T17:12:19",
"InquiryId": "08-CA-036441",
"DisputeUnitCity": "Cleveland",
"CaseClasification": "Unclassified",
"CaseClosedDt": null,
"Created": "2010-10-07T15:32:29",
"CaseDescription": null,
"LastUpd": "2019-10-20T17:17:14",
"LastUpdBy": "1-CGA",
"CaseName": "Sample test case name",
"CaseNumber": "08-CA-036441",
"CaseSource": "Visit",
"DisputeUnitState": "OH",
"CaseStatus": "Open",
"CaseSubType": "CA",
"CaseSubTypeCd": null,
"CaseType": "C",
"CaseLongName": "Long sample test case name",
"Num8a3Discriminatees": null,
"Num8b2Discriminatees": null,
"NumOfEmployees": 146,
"PostElectionSelfCertification": null,
"Potential10j": "N",
"RegionRecommendsPursuing10j": "N",
}

let res = Object.entries(x).map(([k,v])=>{
    return {fieldName:k, value: v}
})
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the information that @cmgchess provided, I was able to implement the solution as follows:

```
    async function loadCaseData(caseNum) {
        Word.run(async function (context) {
            const url = `[URL to my API function]`;

            fetch(url)
                .then(resp => resp.json())
                .then(resp => {
                    console.log('Server Response : ' + JSON.stringify(resp));

                    let fieldList = Object.entries(resp).map(([k, v]) => {
                        return { fieldName: k, fieldValue: v }
                    })
                    return fieldList;
                })
            return context.sync();
        });
    }
```

This retrieves the data from my API function, and stores it in the array as I desired.